# Bootstrap navbar toggle (hamburger menu) only shows when refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Navbar hamburger menu will only show when the user fresh the page. Now sure what it could be or if it's a jquery issue. It could possibly be a turbolink issue but I am not the best with bootstrap so thought i might give a try on this questioning board.

Also I do have the gem boostrap installed have i do have it imported in my scss file and application.js file as well

```
 <header id="header-wrap">
  <!-- Navbar Start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar">
    <%= link_to image_tag("logo2.png"), root_path, :class=>'navbar-brand' %>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="lni-menu"></span>
          <span class="lni-menu"></span>
          <span class="lni-menu"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Categories', categories_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <%= link_to 'Business Directory', business_directory_path, class: 'nav-link dropdown-toggle' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <%= link_to 'Partners', partner_path, class: 'nav-link dropdown-toggle' %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'News & Tech', blogs_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sign-in">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'nav-link dropdown-toggle', 'aria-haspopup' => 'true', 'aria-expanded' => 'false' %>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <%= link_to 'My Ads', myads_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Inbox', conversations_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'dropdown-item' %>
              </div>
            </li>
            <% else %>
            <li>
              <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path, :class => 'nav-link' %> 
              <%= link_to 'Register', pricing_path, :class => 'nav-link' %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <%= link_to 'Post Ad', new_post_path, :class => 'tg-btn' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
    <ul class="mobile-menu">
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Catgeories', categories_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Business Directory', business_directory_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Partners', partner_path %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'News & Tech', blogs_path %> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <%= link_to 'Post Ad', new_post_path %> 
      </li>
      <li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path %>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'My Ads', myads_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
        <% else %>
         <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Register', pricing_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Mobile Menu End -->

  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: please give us live example of it !! if you are using ruby https://repl.it/languages/ruby this is the online editor where you can share project with us

Comment: You don't need to initialize the navbar somehow, do you? Because if you do stuff on document load events, because of turbolinks it will not trigger the document.load event, so you might need to use the turbolink event `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {}`

Comment: maybe this helps with your issue: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/213 try to remove `//=require bootstrap` in application.js